# gnome-screensaver-command --lock, hide password

Tags: gnome, password

If I lock the screen using gnome-screensaver (gnome-screensaver-command --lock) and enter the password, a big dot is shown instead of each character. Is it possible to change this behaviour such that no place-holders are shown if I type in my password (like normally in the shell)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a way to change it but it doesn't completely answer your question.
You can edit `/usr/share/gnome-screensaver/lock-dialog-default.ui` in your favorite text editor (be sure to make a backup first!).  Scroll down and find

```
<object class="GtkEntry" id="auth-prompt-entry">
        <property name="can_focus">True</property>
        <property name="editable">True</property>
        <property name="visibility">False</property>
        <property name="max_length">0</property>
        <property name="text" translatable="yes"/>
        <property name="has_frame">True</property>
        <property name="activates_default">True</property>
</object>
```

`"visibility" = False` causes the password text effect.  You can add a [new property](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkwidget.html#properties-gtkwidget) right below visibility to change the character  (replacing the dot).

```
<property name="invisible-char"> </property>
```

I tried this on Debian 6 but it should work on any Gnome system.  Unfortunately, it needs to show some kind of placeholder so it won't work like a terminal password prompt and show nothing.  The closest I got was using a blank space.  But you could experiment to see what does work.